# Ant installation

Tags: ant

When I am running `ant` command its showing the following output:

> ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.

Comment: which OS are you using ?

Comment: Some of picnic4u's last questions were about Internet Explorer and Asp.net therefore Windows is most likely the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANT_HOME` is is an environment variable which can be set temporary for a command line instance (window) by calling `SET`. Example:

```
SET ANT_HOME="C:\Program Files\Apache-Ant"
```

For permanently setting an environment variable open the `Control Panel` and open `System`. On the tab `Advanced` you should find a button named `Environment Variables`